# How can I store jquery response data in html?

Tags: php, jquery

How can I store response data in HTML?

In JS file I am getting response like `data.firstname`, `data.street`, `data.city` etc. But I don't know how can add response data in HTML.

HTML

```
<h5>Firstname</h5>
<h6><span class="location semi-bold"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Street, City</span></h6>
```

JS File

```
var freetext = $('#freetext').val();
var id = $(":hidden", this).val();
var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();
var dataString = 'freetext=' + freetext + '&id=' + id + '&token=' + token;
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "{!! URL::to('socialfreetext') !!}",
    data: dataString,
    success: function (data) {

        alert(data.firstname);
        alert(data.street);
        alert(data.city);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a span with an where you want to fill in the response:

```
<h5>Firstname</h5>
<h6>
<span class="location semi-bold"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <span id="address">Street, City</span></span></h6>
```

and then do:

```
$("#address").text(data.street + ", " + data.city);
```